# The equation $f(x+a) = g^2(x)$ has no solutions

Tags: calculus, functions

$f(x)=x^2$, $g(x)=2x-1$. Show that the equation $f(x+a)=g^2(x)$ has no solutions if $a>1/4$.

I've reached the stage $x^2+(2a-4)x+a^2+3<0$.

Comment: Check your problem statement, please. As @JibinJoyK notes below you cannot get $x^2+(2a-4)x+a^2+3$ from your equation.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\dfrac{D}{4} = (a-2)^2 - (a^2+3) = 1-4a$.

Comment: how have you established that?. I have used the discriminant b^2-4ac =, but cant seem to understand when I reach x^2+(2a-4)x+a^2+3 our c=(a^2+3)?

Comment: Yes, $c = a^2+3$. But you used $a$ for two different numbers in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x+a)=g^2(x)$ implies
$3x^2-(2a+4)+1-a^2=0$
Since this solution has no solution means discriminant must be less than 0 with respect to quadratic in x.
Hence that give$4a^2+4a+1<0$ which is false for all values of $a$.
Hence this eqn have solution for all values of $a$